# Snap UiView to top after scrolling

Tags: swift, uikit, scrollview

How to make some view snap to the view above as in this GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihEac.jpg
When scrolling up the horizontal buttons are scrolling up with the content but when they reach the top view they stay attached to it.
I can't think of any approach, please help!

Comment: That GIF looks like a standard table view section header. Are you using a table view? Or, do you just have some UI elements in a scroll view, and you want one element to "stop at the top"?

Comment: @DonMag yeah, already found out that this is a tableview(style plain) with section header.